# How to compute the turnover each semester for different article

Tags: sql

I have an table that contains 4 columns:

```
Date   Article  Customer   Turnover
```

I want compute the `AVG` of the Turnover for each customer per article in each 6 months.

```
From January to June ==> Turnover 1 of customer 1 for article 1
From Febrary to July ==> Turnover 2 customer 1 for article 1
From March to August ==> Turnover 3 customer 1 for article 1
From April to September ==> Turnover 4 customer 1 for article 1
From May to Obtober ==> Turnover 5 customer 1 for article 1
From June to November ==> Turnover 6 customer 1 for article 1
From July to December ==> Turnover 7 customer 1 for article 1
```

Then I divide per the `sum` of all the turnover in each 6 months also, like in the xample above but for all the customers and all the articles.

My data like this:

```
      Date        Article  IdCustomer Turnover

    "2016-01-04"    "ATSU"  17182   7146
    "2016-01-05"    "ATSU"  17182   3079    
    "2016-02-06"    "ATSU"  17182   4012
    "2016-02-22"    "MFC"   17182   1398
    "2016-03-04"    "ATSU"  17182   4504
    "2016-04-02"    "ATSU"  17182   5214878
    "2016-05-25"    "ATSU"  17182   2365147
    "2016-06-10"    "ATSU"  17182   2598741
    "2016-07-18"    "ATSU"  17182   1845425
    "2016-08-04"    "ATSU"  17182   845350
    "2016-09-12"    "ATSU"  17182   87418    
    "2016-10-26"    "ATSU"  17182   4012
    "2016-11-25"    "MFC"   17182   1398
    "2016-12-21"    "ATSU"  17182   4504
```

I have the same example Like this for severals customers.

The problem is I can't find a solution to aggregate the months to compute the turnover for each `cusomer` per `article`.

Someone please can help me and give me a solution how can I resolve this problem ?

Thank you;

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database) are you using? Postgres? Oracle? DB2? Firebird?

Comment: I'm using SQL database. I hope that you understand my question because it's complicated a little.

Comment: "SQL" is a query language. **Every** relational database is a "SQL datatabase".

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. I'm using an SQL queries under Palantir Cloud.